# What is the best way to implement static variables per class child? [C++]

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static

In my code, I want all children of class **Component** to have a unique ID that is only shared per their own instances. Right now, I'm implementing such a system like so:

```
template <class componentType>
struct Component {
    static unsigned int ID;
};
```

Example component:

```
struct Transform: public Component<Transform> {

    float x, y, z;
};
```

The ID is assigned using another method. The issue is that I want to have a vector of components as a member variable of another **Entity** class. Additionally, I want said class to have the functions `AddComponent()` and `GetComponent()`. Right now, such an implementation requires that I make both functions templates- this creates a variety of problems in both having to explicitly instance each version of the functions, and in generating a lot of unnecessary code when the only member variable accessed in these functions is the ID, which I know to be common in all **Component** templates.

I could implement a virtual function that is overriden by every child of **Component**, but that would require I copy code for each and every child, as well as couple the ID system with the unrelated component children, which seems like bad practice. What is the best way to assign unique IDs to the children? If it's with templates, then how can I bypass the problem with methods that use the class?

Comment: Is the purpose of `Component` solely to add an ID and be able to collect them in a vector in `Entity`?

Comment: yes, and also to be passed into/out of `Entity` methods

Comment: Would it be an option that this ID is a non-static member, and that you need to call the `Component` constructor in each derived class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to let `Component` inherit from `Component_base` and that this class has a virtual function `get_id` which is implemented by `Component`:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    static unsigned int next_id = 0;

    template<typename T>
    unsigned int get_type_id() {
        static unsigned int id = ++next_id;
        return id;
    }
}

struct Component_base {
    virtual unsigned int get_id() = 0;
};

template <class componentType>
struct Component : public Component_base {

    virtual unsigned int get_id() {
        return Component::ID;
    }

    static unsigned int ID;
};

template <class componentType>
unsigned int Component<componentType>::ID = get_type_id<componentType>();

struct Transform: public Component<Transform> {

    float x, y, z;
};

struct Transform2: public Component<Transform2> {

    float x, y, z;
};

int main() {
    Transform t1;
    Transform2 t2;
    std::cout << t1.get_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << t2.get_id() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```